# Fabric.js line selectable property not getting saved in JSON of the canvas

Tags: javascript, json, canvas, fabricjs

I have a canvas where I am drawing grid lines using the line drawing method of fabric.js. I am defining selection property of those lines as false while drawing which works fine as expected.
Now when I stringify the canvas and retrieve the JSON output I noticed that rest of the properties were extracted except the selection property. What do I need to do to keep the selection property intact in the JSON?
I am using fabric.js-1.4.10

Comment: Hi guys! I just figured this out now. Actually to store additional properties apart from the default ones we need to specify those properties while extracting the JSON of the canvas. Like when we do canvas.toJSON() it just retrieves the default properties and the properties defined in the subclassed function. To solve my problem I had to do canvas.toJSON(['selectable','lockmovementX']) etc....

Answer (score 4):

You can go with following code and you will have all additional properties when you will call toJSON() method :

```
                var obj = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options).set({
                    top: 0,
                    left: 0
                });
                obj.toJSON = (function (toJSON) {
                    return function () {
                        return fabric.util.object.extend(toJSON.call(this), {
                            customProperties: this.customProperties
                        });
                    };
                })(obj.toJSON);
```

Actually as @Abhishek has said in comment than fabric's toJSON() method or any other method that is used to export svg will export only default properties of fabric object. If you want to get your custom added property in export list than you need to override toJSON method as i did in above code, than after when you will use toJSON() method, you will have customproperty in exported JSON.

Comment: after 6 years this issue remains and this solution still works

Comment: thank both who answer and who question